# java wildcard type safety warning

Tags: java, generics

Well, I have an interface which is;

```
public interface abc {
    public<T extends JPanel> T initalize();
}
```

And I'm implementing it. Here is thing, when I defining function like:

```
public class Startup_thePanel extends JPanel implements abc {
   public Startup_thePanel initalize() {

            return this;
    }
}
```

I'm getting warning on function initalize which is 'Type safety: The expression of type ... needs unchecked conversion to conform to ...'.

I can get rid of this with using suppresswarning but I do not want to use it. What am I missing ?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Can you please add the whole warning? By the way, you should your implemented `initialize` method with `@Override`.

Comment: yes you were right, thanks for info, but I got the right answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public interface abc<T extends JPanel> {
    public T initalize();
}

public class Startup_thePanel extends JPanel implements abc<Startup_thePanel> {
   public Startup_thePanel initalize() {

            return this;
    }
}
```

this would make the compiler to know which type of interface your are implementing.

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
public interface abc<T extends JPanel> {
    public T initalize();
}


public class Startup_thePanel extends JPanel implements abc<Startup_thePanel> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public Startup_thePanel initalize() {

            return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't remove the upper bound of the generic type `T`.